# decoder->decode returned false

Tags: android, json

## skia decoder->decode returned false when download image  and display in imageview

```
public class ImageLoader {
Context ctx;

// Initialize MemoryCache
MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();

FileCache fileCache;

//Create Map (collection) to store image and image url in key value pair
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(
                                       new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;

//handler to display images in UI thread
Handler handler = new Handler();

public ImageLoader(Context context){

    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
     ctx=context;
    // Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of 
    // threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

}

// default image show in list (Before online image download)
final int stub_id=R.drawable.index;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    //Toast.makeText(ctx, "IMAGE URL in loader=="+url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Store image and url in Map
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);

    //Check image is stored in MemoryCache Map or not (see MemoryCache.java)
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

    if(bitmap!=null){
        // if image is stored in MemoryCache Map then
        // Show image in listview row
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else
    {
        //queue Photo to download from url
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);

        //Before downloading image show default image 
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    // Store image and url in PhotoToLoad object
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);

    // pass PhotoToLoad object to PhotosLoader runnable class
    // and submit PhotosLoader runnable to executers to run runnable
    // Submits a PhotosLoader runnable task for execution  

    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u; 
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            //Check if image already downloaded
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            // download image from web url
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);

            // set image data in Memory Cache
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);

            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;

            // Get bitmap to display
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);

            // Causes the Runnable bd (BitmapDisplayer) to be added to the message queue. 
            // The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.
            // BitmapDisplayer run method will call
            handler.post(bd);

        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    //CHECK : if trying to decode file which not exist in cache return null
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    // Download image file from web
    try {

        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();

        // Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to file
        // if file not exist then it will create file
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

        // See Utils class CopyStream method
        // It will each pixel from input stream and
        // write pixels to output stream (file)
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);

        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();

        //Now file created and going to resize file with defined height
        // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);

        return bitmap;

    } catch (Throwable ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
           memoryCache.clear();
       return null;
    }
}

//Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){

    try {

        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inSampleSize =2;
        FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
        stream1.close();

      //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

        // Set width/height of recreated image
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=85;

        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) 
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with current scale values
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize= scale;
        FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){

    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    //Check url is already exist in imageViews MAP
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;

        // Show bitmap on UI
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    //Clear cache directory downloaded images and stored data in maps
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

> Advertise() in Advertise class

```
private void getAdvertise()
{

    SQLiteDatabase sd=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql1="select * from "+ Advrtise.TABLE_ADVRTISE ;

    String sql= sql1;
    //Log.e("****", sql+ "** **advt **");
    Cursor cc=sd.rawQuery(sql,  null);      
    while(cc.moveToNext())
    {   
        ad_id.add(cc.getString(0));//ad_id
        ad_imgurl.add(cc.getString(1));//ad_img
        ad_use.add(cc.getString(2));//ad_use
    }

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
     final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            private int index=0;
            public void run() {   
                if(index < ad_use.size()){
                    //Log.i("-=-=-=-=-", index+"-=-=-=---ad use:"+ad_use.get(index));
                    if(ad_use.get(index).equals("android")){
                        imageLoader.DisplayImage(ad_imgurl.get(index), advt);
                    }
                index++;
                }else {
                    index=0;
                }
            }
        };                  
        int delay =0;// 1000; // delay for 1 sec.
        int period = 4000; // repeat every 4 sec.
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
             mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            }
        }, delay, period);          
        }

        protected void animation1() {
              TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
                animation.setDuration(5000);  // animation duration 
                animation.setRepeatCount(5);  // animation repeat count
                animation.setRepeatMode(2);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )      

                advt.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation 

        }
```

> getRelatedNews in Activity Class   /// working fine shows image in imageview

```
private void getRelatedNews() {
    //from related id get news title and img to display
    SQLiteDatabase sd=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql1="select * from "+ News.TABLE_NAME ;

    String sql= sql1;
    Log.e("****", sql+ "** **related **");
    Cursor cc=sd.rawQuery(sql,  null);      
    while(cc.moveToNext())
    {   
        related_id.add(cc.getString(1));//n_id
        related_title.add(cc.getString(2));
        related_desc.add(cc.getString(3));
        related_imgurl.add(cc.getString(5));
        //Log.e("====",cc.getString(1)+"");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < related_id.size(); i++) {
        if(!(related_id.get(i)).isEmpty()){
            //Log.e("====",a+"---check--"+select);
            //if( (related_id.get(i)).equals(bundle_id.get(i)) ) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bundle_id.size(); j++) {
                if((bundle_id.get(j)).equals(related_id.get(i)) ) {
                    Log.e("====",related_id.get(i)+"---match--"+bundle_id.get(j));
                    related_imgurl.add(imgurl.get(i));
                    related_title.add(n_title.get(i));

                    }   
                }// j for

            }/*else {
                    Log.e("---NO MATCH--", related_id+"---"+bundle_id.get(i));
            }   */  
        }//for
     final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {                         

                if(index < related_imgurl.size()){
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(related_imgurl.get(index), rel_image);
                relatedTit.setText(""+related_title.get(index));
                index++;
            }else {
                index=0;
            }
            }
        };                  
        int delay =0;// 1000; // delay for 1 sec.
        int period = 5000; // repeat every 4 sec.
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
             mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            }
        }, delay, period);

}

protected void animation() {
      TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
        animation.setDuration(5000);  // animation duration 
        animation.setRepeatCount(5);  // animation repeat count
        animation.setRepeatMode(2);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )      

        rel_image.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation 

}
```

> Advertise Table in Database file

//-----------------------------TABLE TO STORE NEWS ------------------------

```
   private static final String SQL_CREATE_ADVERTISETBL = "CREATE TABLE " + Advrtise.TABLE_ADVRTISE + " ( " +
            Advrtise._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            Advrtise.COLUMN_advt_id +" INTEGER," +
            Advrtise.COLUMN_advt_img + " TEXT," +
            Advrtise.COLUMN_advt_useby + " TEXT" +      

        " ) ";
```

[check out php file](http://www.sangharshnamanews.in/android/select_advertise.php)

> **Please check all Code and Reply me where i am going wrong ..... 
>   i am trying for couple of days..**